# Adding Text to Caption via Style File

Tags: captions, conditionals

I am trying to add text to a caption via a sty file.

With the following code:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{caption}}{%
{Sample Tex \\ Added Here}
}{}%
```

The style file will add 
"Sample TexAdded Here" to either the beginning or the end of the caption. 
However the line return is not processed.

Is there a way to force a line return?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. So we can see which related packages are loaded.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `\\ ` with `\newline`?